# Parent scope not initiated for nested state (angular ui)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

For the following state definitions and the url `http://localhost/#/foo/bar`, I expect to receive the console output

```
/foo
/foo/bar
```

However, I only get one `/foo`. Is my expectation wrong? What can I do to get the parent controller invoked as well?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('foo', {
      url: '/foo',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('/foo')
      },
      abstract: true
    })
    .state('bar', {
      parent: 'foo',
      url: '/bar',
      controller: function($scope) {
        console.log('/foo/bar')
      }
    })
```

**Update**

Even more strange, when I add

```
onEnter: function() {
  console.log('enter')
}
```

`enter` is printed (but not `/foo/bar`).

**Update 2**

I'd like to add a `resolve` attribute to the parent route and have all children wait for a deferral to be resolved until their controllers get instantiated. This is what it follows: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5854 The scope is used to store the result of the deferral (which is a $http response).

Comment: Do you have a `ui-view` somewhere in the template for the parent that the child can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the abstract parent state, there should be a `ui-view` directive so the child state knows where to insert itself.

```js
.state('foo', {
   url: '/foo',
   abstract: true,
   controller: function($scope) {
     console.log("/foo");
   },
   template: '<ui-view/>'
})
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OskGCBSQGhEXlxaNLZtD?p=preview

**Update 2 response**

You should be able to just add a resolve to the abstract parent state:

```js
resolve: {
  user: function($q, $timeout) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function() {
      deferred.resolve("a resolved user");
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}
```

Here is a working example of that: http://plnkr.co/edit/cm0xUP8LmruHiVBhccuf?p=preview

Comment: This works (both controllers get invoked). Why do I need a `template: '<ui-view/>'` for an abstract state? There's nothing to be rendered for this state...

Comment: An abstract state is just a state that can't be routed or transitioned directly to.  It still behaves like a regular state.  Check out the ui-router documentation on Abstract States for more information: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#abstract-states

Comment: The controller is for the "view" and not really for the state. You need the view to render for the controller to be invoked. Declaring a controller on a state is identical to declaring the controller on an unnamed view inside that state.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, your expectation is wrong: only one route will be matched. If you want to match the second route, you'll need to set the url to `/foo/bar`, but there's no way to hit them both with one URL.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but if you want to access url parameters you can use `/foo/:paramName` and the `$routeParams` service.

Comment: See my `Update 2` for further clarification.